# Powershell query works in prompt, but not in script

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-3.0, domaincontroller

I am trying to make a script that takes input of a hostname and tells me the current logged on user. It works when I run the command one by one on the powershell prompt (as an admin), but doesn't produce the expected output when I run the actual script itself.

Here is the relevant code:

```
$Row.Hostname = $Hostname
$getwmiobject = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_computersystem -computername $Hostname
$Username = $Getwmiobject.username

    if($UserName -eq $NULL) {
    $Row.Username = "No Current Logged on User"
    }
        else {$Row.Username = $Username
    }

$csvfile += $Row

$csvfile |sort-object Hostname | Export-Csv "foo.csv
```

When ran in the command line, I get the correct user. When ran as a script, I get "No Current logged on user". I have no clue why this is happening.

EDIT: I suppose it's important to mention that I have the output writing out to a file, made the changes in the code above.

Comment: Please provide full script, at least the `param()` part, and code around your sample. Is the sample identical to the script, or have you copy/pasted from mulitple places to give us a sample(may be a variable scope problem). At last, did you the script in a console with admin-rights?

Comment: Sorry, I understand more clearly now. This is an excerpt from the end of the script. The only thing I didn't include was how it got the $Hostname variable, but that really shouldn't matter

Comment: okey. Can you insert `Write-Host "Hostname is: $Hostname"; Write-Host "Hostname is of type: $($Hostname.gettype().name)` before the `get-wmiobject...` part and see if it outputs a valid hostname and "String" as type? :)

Comment: All of the hostnames that it pulls are being outputted as valid and as strings. I have a check that simply says `"No Hostname to lookup user"` if the `$hostnames` length is less than 1 as well.

Comment: what about the rights ? did you run the script as admin too ?

Comment: Yes, both the script and the line by line were run as admin

Comment: do you run the script from a terminal server session? In a terminal services session, UserName returns the name of the user that is logged on to the console—not the user logged on during the terminal service session.

Comment: Right, but the computer's queried are in fact logged onto the console. The script is ran in a terminal service session, but that doesn't explain why it works when done line-by-line rather than by the script.

Comment: So, apparently when I run the script, it comes back with `"Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable`. When run line by line, I do not get this issue and get the proper info back.

Comment: are you sure you are running a console session (mstsc.exe /admin) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whatever input you have for the `$Hostname` variable for extra characters, such as a newline `` `n ``. When you type it out, it may not give you an error and work because it doesn't have to process things like that.

Comment: That was it. There was a `n at the end of each hostname so it could add a new one to the array. Took that line out and it worked. Thanks!